# Weak form of Dirichlet's theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

Dirichlet's Theorem on arithmetic progressions is often stated as something like:

> Every arithmetic progression where the first term and the difference are coprime contains an infinite amount of primes.

But can be rewritten as:

> If $(a,m) = 1$ then there are infinite primes $p$ such that $p\equiv a\pmod m$.

I'm trying (fruitlessly) to come up with an elementary proof of its weak version.

> If $(a,m) = 1$ then there is at least one prime $p$ such that $p\equiv a\pmod m$.

Note that if this is stated in terms of arithmetic progressions then it would not be a weak version (once you find one prime, consider the sequence with difference $m$ and first term $p + m$).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a$ be a non-prime, and suppose we know that there is a prime $p$ congruent to $a$ modulo $n$ for every $n$ relatively prime to $a$. Then for every positive integer $k$, there is a prime congruent to $a$ modulo $m^k$.  From this it follows that there are infinitely many primes congruent to $a$ modulo $m$.

So for non-primes $a$, the weak version is equivalent to Dirichlet's Theorem. For primes $a$ the weak version is trivial. But from the assumption that for all $n$ relatively prime to $a$, there is a prime *other* than $a$ congruent to $a$ modulo $n$, we can again derive Dirichlet's Theorem. And if we are allowed to let $a$ vary, we can find a non-prime $a'$ of the form $a+qm$, and again conclude that there are infinitely many primes congruent to $a$ modulo $m$.

Comment: Well, those are some days I'm not getting back.

Comment: It does feel initially much weaker.

Comment: Here is an equivalence between (initially) weaker and stronger forms of Bunyakovsky's conjecture on prime values of polynomials.  Dirichlet's theorem is the case of linear polynomials: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226794/on-a-possible-equivalence-of-bunyakovsky-conjecture